# ToolStripMenuItem show sub menu on Mouse hover in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

I am having a windows form menu strip control. And having ToolStripMenu Item with text of "Click Me". Now i want to display its sub menu toolstrip items on Mouse Hover Event of the "Click Me" ToolStrip. Can any one suggest how its can be done.

[image]

Here on mousehover event i want to display its sub menu item like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle `MouseHover` event of the items and then using [`ShowDropDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.showdropdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, open the dropdown. This way, menus will open on hover rather than click.

For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        x.MouseHover += (obj, arg) => ((ToolStripDropDownItem)obj).ShowDropDown();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem clickmeeToolStripMenuItem
this.clickmeeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
this.clickmeeToolStripMenuItem.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.clickmeeToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover);

//ADD THIS METHOD TO YOUR EVENT METHOD

clickmeeToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
```